# Sonarqube totals wrong

Tags: sonarqube

Sonarqube is showing incorrect total for projects and issues.

Total projects says 4 however there are only 2. Claims there are 78 bugs but there are none, and none get displayed in the results section. (see below)

[image]

I've checked the database a grouping the `[projects]` table by `[project_uuid]` only returns 2 rows.

Sonarqube v6.2 is being used, with an SQL Server database if that makes any difference. Could this be a setup issue, I only setup this instance a few days ago but I am not sure where to check other than the database where the projects table at least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When your issue counts are scrambled like this, it means the ElasticSearch index is corrupted.

- shut the server down
- delete *$SONARQUBE_HOME/data/es*
- start the server back up

Startup will take a little longer because there's an added delay while the index is rebuilt. The duration of this delay is dependent on the size of your instance.

Once your server comes back up, your numbers should be right.

Comment: We deleted the `$SONARQUBE_HOME/data/es6` but this didn't work.

Comment: Just in case... I had `$SONARQUBE_HOME/data/es6` as well. Deleting it for me worked